# Implementing Prototype-style class structure with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs, highcharts

I've been using heavily Prototype's way of defining classes and subclasses:

```
// properties are directly passed to `create` method
var Person = Class.create({
  initialize: function(name) {
    this.name = name;
  },
  say: function(message) {
    return this.name + ': ' + message;
  }
});

// when subclassing, specify the class you want to inherit from
var Pirate = Class.create(Person, {
  // redefine the speak method
  say: function($super, message) {
    return $super(message) + ', yarr!';
  }
});

var john = new Pirate('Long John');
john.say('ahoy matey');
```

I'm working with my 2.3.8 Rails app and planning to use Highcharts (charting JS library). My problem is that Highcharts is dependent on jQuery (or MooTools).

Is there a way to modify Prototype-style defined classes and subclasses into jQuery format? Or should I change my existing classes into plain JavaScript? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both Prototype and jQuery together on the same page by using jQuery.noConflict(). Is there a reason that you only want to use one? Use Prototype for most things since you seem comfortable with it and jQuery for the plug-ins that require it...

```
// during loading
jQuery.noConflict();

// later when you want to manipulate things
jQuery('div.hideme').hide(); // jQuery
$('#somethingElse').hide();  // Prototype
```

Comment: Thank James for the answer. I'm not sure how HighCharts plugin is using the jQuery library - I would assume it's using $-method instead of jQuery('') one.

Comment: Properly-written jQuery add-ins shouldn't depend on $ being assigned to jQuery. You'll be able to tell quickly by adding jQuery.noConflict() and then trying to display a chart. If the chart displays properly, they have correctly implemented their add-in. If not, I would file a bug report with the developer. It's not hard to make add-ins agnostic to the name of the jQuery object.

Comment: Yes, oftentimes functions take $ as a parameter and pass in jQuery as a function. Very bad idea to assume the meaning of $ when writing plugins.